# Can any repeating sequence be expressed in a generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Suppose we have a sequence $a$ with a repeating pattern of length $k$. For simplicity, we can express it as:

$$
a=\{c_0,c_1,...,c_{k-1},c_0,c_1,...\}
$$

Where $a_n$ is the $n$th term, starting from $n=0$, can a generating function be found for such a sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short Answer

Yes, we can turn any such pattern into the following OGF.
$$
A(x)=\frac{c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+c_{k-2}x^{k-2}+...+c_1x+c_0}{1-x^k}
$$

## Behind the Answer

Not that a repeating pattern is commonly used for a generating function, but if you have a repeating pattern such that is naively defined by a relationship with a previous index, it'll always have this format. Of course if you have a repeating sequence that's a bit less trivial it will have a different form, but this is just a proof that there must exist a generating function for any infinitely repeating sequence.

We can set a recurrence relation using $a_n$:

$$
a_{n+k}=a_n; a_0=c_0,a_1=c_1,...,a_{k-1}=c_{k-1}
$$

We look to using an ordinary generating function (OGF) $A(x)$ for our purposes:

$$
A(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n
$$

Note that with most generating functions, $x$ is just a dummy variable that needs to be algebraically upheld on some range of values with our manipulation.

$$
a_{n+k} = a_n
$$
$$
a_{n+k}x^{n+k} = a_nx^{n+k}
$$
$$
\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n+k}x^{n+k}=\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^{n+k}
$$
$$
\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n-a_{k-1}x^{k-1}-a_{k-2}x^{k-2}-...-a_1x-a_0=x^k\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n
$$
$$
A(x)-c_{k-1}x^{k-1}-c_{k-2}x^{k-2}-...-c_1x-c_0=x^kA(x)
$$
$$
A(x)-x^kA(x)=c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+c_{k-2}x^{k-2}+...+c_1x+c_0
$$
$$
A(x)(1-x^k)=c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+c_{k-2}x^{k-2}+...+c_1x+c_0
$$
$$
A(x)=\frac{c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+c_{k-2}x^{k-2}+...+c_1x+c_0}{1-x^k}
$$
And at this point since we've found an expression for $A(x)$ without the use of the recurrence so we'd be done. However, despite being potentially messier to get what you seek, I quite enjoy the ones below:
$$
A(x)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_jx^j}{1-x^k}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_jx^j\sum_{n\geq0}x^{nk}
$$

Comment: Feels like there's gotta be some connection to the rational numbers and geometric series